# In Google Data Studio, how can I concat multiple row values in one column grouped by IDs in another column?

Tags: sql, database, concatenation, data-analysis, looker-studio

This is my first post on here. I am having a hard time coming up with a solution to an issue I'm having in creating a product bundle analysis on Google Data studio. I know that my problem can be easily resolved using normal SQL syntax, such as GROUP_CONCAT, but since GDS is funky when I comes to calculated fields, I can not find a way to concat multiple values from a column into a single string of comma separated values. GDS is what we use for our executive analysis decision making at my company so I can't do this anywhere else really.

My data source is a sales table with an "Order_Number" column, a "Part_Number" column, and a "Quantity_Sold" column. Each row contains an individual part number that makes up each unique order number. This means that there will be multiple instances of the same order number in the "Order_Number" column to show line by line the parts that make up the order with their respective Quantity sold each. Here is a visual:

| Order_Number | Part_Number | Quantity_Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc | 2 |
| 123 | def | 1 |
| 123 | ghi | 3 |
| 456 | abc | 6 |
| 789 | abc | 1 |
| 789 | def | 2 |

My main objective is to produce:

| Order_Number | Part_Number_concat | Quantity_Sold | Bundle_Frequency_2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | abc, def, ghi | 6 | 50 |
| 789 | abc, def | 3 | 20 |

We want to find which products are commonly purchased together in the same order and we want to sort to show which "bundles" are most frequent(basically a count).

I tried the following calculated field formula using a self join blend, but this only joins two of the parts and creates tons of duplicates. Ive tried many other formulas and workarounds, but this is what got me the furthest.

```
case 
     when (Order_Number1 = Order_Number2) and (Part1 != Part2) 
then CONCAT(Part2, ", ", Part2)
     else ""
end
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. I just wish GDS/looker studio would step it up and fully integrate SQL.

Answer (score 1):

To concat Quantity_Sold based on Order_Number, you could just use this formula in the Calculated field:

```
CONCAT(Order_Number)
```

but you probably already know it.

To concat Part_Number, the nearest workaround I found is this:

```
CASE
  WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Part_Number) = 1
    THEN MAX(Part_Number)
  ELSE CONCAT(MAX(Part_Number), ", ", MIN(Part_Number))
END
```

However, it would work only if you have two part numbers, which can return only two parts.
[The result of the above furmula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn6A9.png)

Here is the [list of supported functions](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/table/6379764?hl=en) in calculated fields in Google Data Studio. GROUP_CONCAT(), for example, would solve your issue but it is not on the list.

Another workaround would be to concat it in the source you import data from. For example, if you take data from Google Sheets, you could write a Google Apps Script to concat the fields or some other way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I've seen the MIN MAX method floating around on a few forums online and it indeed works, but unfortunately my bundles can be made up of any number of combinations. It could possibly be more than 10 in one bundle if customers are repeatedly buying that same combination. Our sales table is stored in Big Query so that's what I am linking to. Since it seems I have reached the limitations of GDS, I going to try to get my intended results using the Big Query SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I was not able to find a solution within Google Data Studio due to its limitations on SQL, but since I pull my source data from tables on Big Query, I was able to use the table query feature to formulate my data to be used by GDS.

For anyone running into the same problem as I did, If you are using Big Query or another data source where you can directly transform the table data, use this:

```sql
SELECT
  Order_Number,
  array_to_string(array_agg(Part_Number), ', ') as parts, 
  sum(Quantity_Sold) as total_quantity_sold 
FROM `SalesTable` 
group by Order_Number;
```

I find it frustrating that such a simple formula can be used in any other SQL environment besides GDS. Oh well.